# Quadratic Formula on Java semi-colon error

Tags: java, syntax-error, formula, quadratic

I wrote code for finding the roots of a quadratic formula in Java. However, I get the error that I'm missing a semi-colon in line 6, even though I have one there. What's going on?

```
public class Lab2{
   public static void main (String[] args){
    double a = 1;
    double b = 2;
    double c = 4;
    double d = (math.pow(b, 2))-(4*a*c));

    if (d < 0)
    {
        String.out.println("There are no real roots.");
     } else if (a == 0) {
        x3 = (-1)*c*b;
        String.out.println("The root is " + x3);
     } else if (a != 0) {
        x1 = (((-1)*b) + (d))/(2*a);
        x2 = (((-1)*b) - (d))/(2*a);
        String.out.println(" The roots are " + x1 + " and " + x2 + ".");
     }



  }
}
```

Comment: line 6 remove last )

Comment: The classname is `Math` not `math`. Java class names are case sensitive. And what is `String.out.println`, did you mean `System.out.println`?

Answer (score 1):

```
    double d = (math.pow(b, 2))-(4*a*c));
```

This line has an extra closing parenthesis.

Try this:

```
    double d = (Math.pow(b, 2))-(4*a*c);
```